# sidebar gone for gnome-files on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nautilus, 22.04

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Somehow my side menu on files is disappeared. How do  I get it back? Here is a screenshot from my home director.

[image]
There was a sidebar in the highlighted place, but it is no more now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the hamburger menu (3 parallel line menu) on the top bar of the `Files` window and select `Show Sidebar`.
[image]