# Ubuntu 22.04 no sidebar when downloading/uploading files

Tags: nautilus

When downloading/uploading files, there is no sidebar in the file viewer. See screenshot.

[image: screenshot of not having a sidebar]

Just to be clear, [sidebar gone for gnome-files on ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418297/sidebar-gone-for-gnome-files-on-ubuntu-22-04) is not the issue at hand, as this happens only when uploading/downloading files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regarding Ubuntu version:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Regarding Desktop:
`GNOME Verion: 42.2`

Regarding what programs:
Firefox, specifically `Mozilla Firefox 103.0.2`
Chromium, specifically `Chromium 104.0.5112.79 snap`

Regarding what I am trying to download/upload: When attempting to download literally anything, an image, a video, right clicking a website and clicking "save-as", I get a window that opens, and there is no sidebar on it, making navigation fairly difficult. Another example: if I try to attach a file to an email, the same issue occurs.

Comment: Provide information on your Ubuntu version and desktop, an on what program, including version, you use for uploading/downloading.

Comment: I have now added additional information. If additional specifics are required, I can provide them, but given that the problem is not tied to a specific web browser, but rather how the OS allows me to select where to download/what file to upload, I assume that information is not helpful.

Comment: Please let me know if the new edits are sufficient.

Comment: the current version of GNOME for 22.04.1 LTS is 42.2 Your is 41.7 Was this an upgrade from an earlier version, an installation from scratch or have you made some other modifications or changes to the system? I can't reproduce your issue as with my instance of 22.04.1 GNOME 42.2 using the X11 windowing system it performs as it should. I do notice [this reference to v41.7](https://www.linuxcompatible.org/story/gnome-417-released/) though. Did you upload it from some non Ubuntu source or other?

Comment: This system was upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04. I don't recall doing anything specifically with gnome. This was not an issue until recently (well after the upgrade from 20.04). I will see if I can get GNOME to the current version.

Comment: Huh. So it appears I was mistaken. I am on 42.2. Not sure why a different window reported 41.7. I have edited the question. (I am also using the X11 windowing system)

Comment: As I'm unable to reproduce your issue, the only suggestion I have at present is to load 22.04.1 from a live USB (or DVD) session and select the `Try Ubuntu` option to see if you can replicate the issue that way. If it works properly in that test environment, consider backing up essential data and re-installing the OS from scratch to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is described in https://askubuntu.com/a/1498327/1754590:

Install the `dconf-editor` and set the value `org.gtk.gtk4.Settings.FileChooser` to a value bigger than `0`.

Answer (score -1):

View image in
https://i.stack.imgur.com/COPRZ.jpg

The solution with firefox is remove snap firefox and install PPA reopository (only works in firefox. Your history data all is safe if update from 20.04 to 22.04)

Step 1: Remove the Firefox Snap by running the following command in a new Terminal window:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Step 2: Add the (Ubuntu) Mozilla team PPA to your list of software sources by running the following command in the same Terminal window:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

Step 3: Next, alter the Firefox package priority to ensure the PPA/deb/apt version of Firefox is preferred. This can be done using a slither of code from FosTips (copy and paste it whole, not line by line):

```
echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

Step 4: Since you’ll (hopefully) want future Firefox upgrades to be installed automatically, Balint

```
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
```

Step 5: Finally, install Firefox via apt by running this command:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: In a stunning twist, this did not work. I'm not really sure why you assumed reinstalling firefox would solve a problem that affects both firefox and chromium.