# Left panel (sidebar / tree view) missing in open file dialog

Tags: nautilus, dialog

On my Ubuntu 22.04 in "open file" dialogs somehow the left panel for the tree view of the system is missing and I cannot get it back.
The problem exists for all dialogs of all programs (Firefox, Thunderbird, Inkscape, Chromium, ...).

I guess I somehow hit a shortcut by accident?

[image]

In Nautilus itself it works as expected.

What I tried so far:

- Pressing `F9` was not working.
- There is not right-click option in the dialog itself.
- Searching in the settings of Ubuntu gave no success.
- Gnome Tweak does not seem to have a control for this.

I found a duplicate to my problem: [Ubuntu 22.04 no sidebar when downloading/uploading files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424229)

Comment: Did you restart the system? Can you test with another (possibly newly created) user?

Comment: @FedKad: Restart has no effect. But I created a new user and there the sidebar is visible. So that indicates that it's coupled to my user account. But how can I reset it?

Comment: I haven't found any (seemingly) relevant key in `dconf-editor`. You can investigate further there by trial-and-error. If you find the answer, please do not hesitate to answer your question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to install `dconf-editor` and search in the `dconf-editor` for "sidebar-width". The value `org.gtk.gtk4.Settings.FileChooser` was set to `0`.

Thanks @FedKad for the support!

Comment: There is no "sidebar" key. Possibly you mean "sidebar-width", but even for this key, a value of zero (or any value smaller that the minimum one) will set the sidedar width to a minimum width and you will still have a narrow sidebar. BTW, I am using 23.10 and your system may behave slightly different.

Comment: True, I corrected the answer. Thanks. I also double checked and the sidebar vanishes if the value is set to `0` on 22.04